# Unity is having trouble compiling a valid C# class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I'm working on a simple game right now, and Unity and it's giving me a strange error. I have a C# class called `Level` which has a constructor that takes four arguments:

```
using System;

namespace World
{
    public class Level
    {
        public Grid grid { get; private set; }
        public int starty { get; private set; }
        public int endy { get; private set; }

        public Level(int width, int height, int starty, int endy)
        {
            this.grid = new Grid(width, height);
            this.starty = starty;
            this.endy = endy;
        }
    }
}
```

And a class called `WorldGen` which still isn't much of anything:

```
using System;
using World;

namespace WorldGen
{
    public class WorldGen
    {
        public Level GenerateLevel(int width, int height, int starty, int endy)
        {
            Level level = new Level(width, height, starty, endy); // Line 47

            Grid grid = level.grid; // Line 49

            // ...

            return level;
        }
    }
}
```

This is really straightforward to me, (and GenerateLevel is not called anywhere in the project yet). Calling `csc` in PowerShell compiles all the files in the directory without any errors or warnings.

But in the Unity window, I'm getting errors that don't make much sense to me:

> Assets/WorldGen/WorldGen.cs(47:65): error CS1729: The type 'Level'
>   does not contain a constructor that takes '4' arguments
>   Assets/WorldGen/WorldGen.cs(49:31): error CS1061: The type 'Level'
>   does not contain a definition for ''grid' and no extension method
>   'grid' of type 'Level' can be found (are you missing a using directive
>   of an assembly reference?)

It's like `WorldGen` has access to the class `Level` but can't see any of its public methods.

It seems to me like Unity is just wrong about my code, but from experience that's rarely the case. I just don't know what it wants from me. `Level` is in the project directory. It's constructor takes 4 arguments, I'm passing it the types it needs, and it has the public `grid` field. What gets me is that I know this code compiles on its own when unity is taken out of the picture.

I don't know what it is I'm missing, and I was wondering if anyone out there could give me a clue.

Comment: Sounds like it's resolving to a different `Level` class... As an aside, it would be a good idea to follow .NET naming conventions - capitalize your property name leading characters.

Comment: class WorldGen in namespace WorldGen is also looking for trouble tbh :)

Comment: Huh, I thought it was common to have a namespace with the same name as a core class in that namespace...
Also, thank you muchly Jon Skeet! There's definitely another class elsewhere in the project called level!

Comment: @JonSkeet When working specifically with Unity3D, many devs mirror Unity's code style, which doesn't capitalize the first letter of property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have a naming conflict with Level. Try specifying the namespace explicitly:

`World.Level level = new World.Level(width, height, starty, endy);`